# Recuperar videos mais vistos do canal do youtube

Tags: youtube-api

Tem como eu recuperar os 5 videos mais vistos do meu canal do Youtube para colocar em meu site?

Comment: Pode ser em JQuery ou PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `search.list` permite que você procure por vídeos, canais ou listas de reprodução que correspondam a critérios especificados. Você pode pesquisar com base em propriedades de vídeo, palavras-chave ou tópicos (ou uma combinação destes), e você pode ordenar os resultados com base em fatores tais como data de criação, visualizações, etc.

**Meus vídeos mais vistos:** Essa solicitação recupera todos de vídeo do usuário autenticado e os lista em ordem decrescente por visualização (*viewCount*), veja o exemplo abaixo.

```
GET {base_URL}/search?part=snippet
                     &forMine=true
                     &order=viewCount
                     &maxResults=5
                     &type=video
```

Como outras solicitações da API de dados do YouTube, o método `search.list` retorna a representação JSON padrão.

Caso precise de mais detalhes sobre as APIs de requisição: [YouTube API Requests](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests#search)

Comment: amigo o que eu devo colocar neste base_URL por gentileza. e outra coisa tem como limitar a quantidade de dados retornado tipo os 10 videos?

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo atualizei a resposta com a opção `maxResults` que limita a quantidade. Sobre a `base_URL`, você troca por *https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3*. Está tudo explicado na documentação do link no fim da minha resposta.

Comment: olha dei uma olhada e estou usando esta url get: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&type=video&maxResults=2&key={YOUR_API_KEY}. Criei uma key de aplicativos de navegador e coloquei na URL citada, mas ta gerando o seguinte erro: `Invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions.` O que eu fiz de errado?

Comment: amigo eu removi o forMine da url e deu tudo certo. Espero ter feito ceretinho. Se não fiz por gentileza me corrija. Obrigado

Comment: Acredito que sem o `forMine` ele identifique o seu canal automaticamente, sem problemas. O erro que estava acontecendo antes era pois alguma parte das requisições da URL não estava correta. Fico feliz que tenha funcionado, se a resposta foi útil considere marcar ela como *resposta correta*. :-)